# Convert varchar to datetime SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008, datetime, varchar

I have a column of Date and Time like this:

```
  20/Mar/2013:02:28:47
  20/Mar/2013:02:28:43
  20/Mar/2013:02:28:47
  20/Mar/2013:02:28:47
  20/Mar/2013:02:28:47
  20/Mar/2013:02:28:47
  20/Mar/2013:02:28:41
  20/Mar/2013:02:28:46
```

the datatype of this column is set to "varchar". I just need to convert the following format of column to:

```
  20/03/2013:02:28:47
  20/03/2013:02:28:43
  20/03/2013:02:28:47
  20/03/2013:02:28:47
  20/03/2013:02:28:47
  20/03/2013:02:28:47
  20/03/2013:02:28:41
  20/03/2013:02:28:46
```

also can i change its datatype from varchar to SQL date and time datatype!
I am trying with my query like:

```
 SELECT convert(mydatetimecolumn,105) from mytable
```

but it gives me the result like:

```
   1900-04-16 00:00:00.000
   1900-04-16 00:00:00.000
   1900-04-16 00:00:00.000
   1900-04-16 00:00:00.000
   1900-04-16 00:00:00.000
```

How can I overcome this problem? can somebody help me please? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why are you storing datetime values in a string column? Also can you show an example of what March 4th looks like? Does it have the leading 0 or not?

Comment: actually i am importing data from an excel file so

Comment: Ok, so why does your Excel file have such horrible formats?

Comment: lols because actually it has been generated from a webserver!

Comment: That can be fixed too, you know.

Comment: yes i think the only solution seems to be!

Answer (score 4):

Here is one possible solution, assuming that you don't have any junk in this column that can't be converted correctly (which is entirely possible, since for some reason you decided to store dates as strings).

Note that **this is a sample** and not something you can apply directly to your existing table. This is on purpose. It is intentionally created in tempdb and with fictitious/meaningless table names so you can try it out instead of trying anything directly against your production table first. Because, what happens if you run an update against your real table, and it doesn't work like you expect? Do you have a backup?

```
USE tempdb;
GO

CREATE TABLE dbo.floob(splunge VARCHAR(32));

INSERT dbo.floob(splunge) VALUES('20/Mar/2013:02:28:47'),('4/Mar/2013:02:25:32');

UPDATE dbo.floob SET splunge = CONVERT(CHAR(8), 
  CONVERT(DATETIME, REPLACE(LEFT(splunge,
  CHARINDEX(':', splunge)-1), '/', ' '), 13), 112) 
  + ' ' + RIGHT(splunge, 8);

SELECT splunge FROM floob;
GO

SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME, splunge) FROM floob;
GO

ALTER TABLE dbo.floob ALTER COLUMN splunge DATETIME;
GO

SELECT splunge FROM floob;
GO
```

For your real table, again assuming there is no junk in the table, you would just do the `UPDATE` and `ALTER` parts (of course putting in your real table and column names instead of `floob` and `splunge`).

[SQLfiddle example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/2e40a/3)

Comment: i dont need to create a new table! :(

Comment: @user2496503 I know that. This is a *sample* you can try out on your own and make sure it works, before you do it to your *real* table. You didn't give us the real table or column names anyway, so I'm not sure why you would expect a solution that would work against the objects you have.

Answer (score 0):

One way;

```
declare @s varchar(32) = '20/Mar/2013:02:28:46'

select cast(stuff(replace(@s, '/', ' '), 12, 1, ' ') as datetime)

(No column name)
2013-03-20 02:28:46.000
```

Use

```
cast(stuff(replace(@s, '/', ' '), len(@s) - 8, 1, ' ') as datetime)
```

If the day is `d` or `dd`.